# Login failed to database

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am using the following code to backup my database...

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LIC;Trusted_Connection = yes")
cmd = New SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE LIC to disk='C:\Backup\ICLS.bak'", con)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

But I get this error

> `Cannot open database "LIC" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'mono-PC\mono'.`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It will still fail, but it will print a number (the State of the Exception).  A table is below that lists the possible states and the reasons why they might occur (from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351.aspx).  See those links for resolution.

```
try
  Dim con As SqlConnection
  Dim cmd As SqlCommand
  con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LIC;Trusted_Connection = yes")
  cmd = New SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE LIC to disk='C:\Backup\ICLS.bak'", con)
  con.Open()
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  con.Close()
catch e as SqlException
    Console.WriteLine("State: " & e.State)
end try
```

Possible States:

```
ERROR STATE ERROR DESCRIPTION
2 and 5     Invalid userid
6           Attempt to use a Windows login name with SQL Authentication
7           Login is disabled, and the password is incorrect
8           Password mismatch
9           Invalid password
11 and 12   Valid login but server access failure
13          SQL Server service paused
18          Change password required
```

Comment: From the links: State 1 is a generic message displayed at the client - there will be a more descriptive error in SQL Server (and perhaps the Windows Application Log). This blog should help you identify the precise nature of the authentication failure.  So check your Windows Event Log.

Comment: Note that the message is kept fairly nondescript to prevent information disclosure to unauthenticated clients.   In particular, the 'State' will always be shown to be '1' regardless of the nature of the problem.  Copied from the link you provided.

Comment: Are you sure that this database is running in SQL Express, on your local machine, with Windows Authentication?  Have you ever connected successfully before?

Comment: For the Event Log, depending on your OS: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer or http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/snap_event_viewer.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Not sure if this might help?
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

Comment: Find log at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG